# When I run the azure function project locally (VSCode) after I add azure function proxy I'm getting 'Worker was unable to load function" error

Tags: node.js, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

When I run (func run) the azure function project locally (VSCode) after I add azure function proxy I'm getting 'Worker was unable to load function" console error. However function locally run perfectly after that console error.

What could be the reason for that console error

***Error***

```
Worker was unable to load function get-user: 'TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_VALUE]: The argument 'id' must be a non-empty string. Received '''
```

[image]

Comment: Seems to be related to https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4809

Comment: It looks like a GUID is generated but no instance is generated. (It shouldn't generate GUIDs just after hoststart) This should be a bug, maybe you should give [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback).

Comment: The good news is that this error will not have any effect on your future use of this function, because the current function id will be discarded.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that the GUID of the function is generated but no real instance is generated. Therefore, trying to access the function GUID through proxy will report an error because it does not exist at all. I don't think you need to worry about this. This should be a bug, but the good news is that it will not have any effect on your function, because you will never use this GUID any more. A new instance and corresponding GUID will be generated when you trigger the function, and the previous GUID will be discarded.